# STS does not start anymore

Tags: spring-tool-suite

All of sudden STS does not start anymore. I have deleted and downloading the STS again but it does not start.

spring-tool-suite-3.8.3.RELEASE-e4.6.2-win32-x86_64

Any suggestions?

Comment: what does it say? any error message showing up? or maybe a log file or a crash dump in the sts home folder?

Comment: Hi,

i found that the problem was setting the right variable(path) in the Environment Variables. Now i have set Path=C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_121\bin and it works again.

This youtube video gave me the clue. Set the PATH: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Wh7nMRJMjBY

Thx for your response.

Regards,
Arend van der Kolk

Comment: glad to hear that you found the root cause and got it fixed. And thanks for providing the answer here.

Answer (score 1):

i found that the problem was setting the right variable(path) in the Environment Variables. Now i have set Path=C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_121\bin and it works again.

This youtube video gave me the clue. Set the PATH: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Wh7nMRJMjBY

Thx for your response.

Regards,
Arend van der Kolk

Comment: The video link is broken

Answer (score 1):

My problem I found out resides in sts.ini file, open it and make sure everything is right. In my particular case, I messed up the path to lombok.